# How can I get this Mechanism?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I want to get the text of an anchor tag when the user clicked on it. and I also want to store that text inside PHP variable.this should be implemented through using javascript and PHP . (no jquery)

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your request is, that php is serversided, which means that at the time your user presses an anchor tag, the php already finished loading

Comment: the text which I'm talking about is stored in the database. for example, It is  name of the topic . and after a user clicked on topic I want fetch the content of that topic ..that's why I need the name of the topic. sorry for my bad english I hope you will understand.

Comment: So if I understood you correctly, you want to fetch a text to put into a php variable when the anchor tag is pressed. You might need to tell me what you want to do with the php variable, but judging from how this sounds, you might need to use jquery->ajax

Comment: It sounds like you need to use JSON/AJAX if I understand what you're trying to do correctly.

Comment: I don't want to use JSON/AJAX or Jquery.only javascript and PHP.I want to use that PHP varible to fecth content from the database for example, select content from topics where unique_topic=that_achor_text_name_In PHP_VARIABLE;

Comment: I'm afraid you cannot achieve this without jquery unless you get all the data from the database in the php while loading the site, which u can then pass on to the javascript part. I'm just guessing you want to display the content, which shouldn't be a problem then

Comment: try firing up the query in your php and loop through the result to create an array. you then pass on the array to javascript with var array = <?php echo json_encode($yourarray); ?>; You can the search for your data in that array as soon as an anchor tag is pressed

Comment: Thanks for your answer I will try it.